# Turn VS Address-Sanitizer off and on or speed up while debugging?

Tags: c++, debugging, windows-10, visual-studio-2022, address-sanitizer

I've instrumented my debug code, the .EXE and all .DLLs. I'm tracking down an allocation bug that corrupts memory after about 5 minutes. With the code instrumented, it runs at less than 1% of the normal speed, so after 8 hours, the code isn't close to where the bug might occur. When I removed Address-Sanitizer and then instrumented only one small .DLL, it slows down just as much. How can I start my code debugging with full instrumentation, then turn off Address-Sanitizer, then turn it back on 5 minutes later when approaching the code where I think the bug is?

I'm enabling Address-Sanitizer in the project properties, C/C++ General Enable Address Sanitizer Yes (/fsanitize=address). I'm running VS2022 Community on Windows 10 Pro.

According to Google and Microsoft docs, the performance hit should be less than 2X, so my bug should be detected in about 10 minutes. Am I using Address-Sanitizer incorrectly, or is there a better setup?

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: "less than 1% of the normal speed" is amazingly slow even for Valgrind, let alone address sanitizer. I want to say you are using it wrong, but there's very little to help you here, you question is essentially "I have some code on a project, am doing things correctly?". On another note `/fsanitize` is a compiler option. So you don't turn it on and off, you are either compiling your code with sanitizer support or without. After 5 minutes you won't have a program compiled with different options

Comment: The program is 32 bit with LARGEADDRESSAWARE set. It consists of an .exe and about 140 .dlls. It makes about 2.2 million memory allocations soon after startup to load a cache. It makes a lot fewer allocations after that. Without Address-Sanitizer, Task Manger shows 20% CPU, which is normal. With Sanitizer, CPU is about 28%.

Comment: Chromium component build with even more dll files is not such slow. "I have some code on a project, am doing things correctly?" - fix that with posting a [mcve].

Comment: The initial cache loading with 2.2 million allocations is happening at normal speed, using HeapAlloc. However, HeapFree is taking a consistent 225 ms each time with Sanitize, <1 ms without Sanitize. Is there any way to speed that up?

Comment: You seem to be hitting some corner case in Windows implementation of Asan. In particular `HeapFree` is intercepted by Asan and additional work done in it may be the reason for the slowdown. But as others pointed out your chances to get useful advice without reprocase are low.

Comment: So, OP, can you make a [mre] that mimics the startup behaviour of your app?  Doesn't sound so hard...

Comment: _Is there any way to speed that up?_ At the risk of masking the bug, maybe don't call `HeapFree` during the startup phase?

Comment: GFlags found a couple of problems, which, when fixed, seemed to be the bug. They didn't appear related to the blowup, so we'll see. GFlags was certainly faster, so thank you Paul for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution that using `ASAN` might be to use `gflags`.  This allocates memory in such a way that memory overwrites are usually caught straightaway without impacting performance unduly.  The main downside is that a 32 bit program might run out of addressing space, but it would cost you nothing to try it.

The magic sauce is:

`gflags -p /decommit /enable my_app.exe`

and:

`gflags -p /disable my_app.exe`

Worth a shot, anyway.

Please note that:

- after running `gflags`, you need to restart your app
- You have to run `gflags` in a command shell running 'As Administrator'

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I've used gflags over the years, but not with these arguments, so I'll see what it shows.

Comment: To be fair Asan is capable of detecting more types of bugs than traditional Efence-like debuggers.